# How to replace "<td>XXX</td></tr" for "</br>XXX"

Tags: html, regex, replace, character-encoding, notepad++

I'm using notepad++ and coding some tables in html. However I need to replace:

```
<td>XXX</td></tr>
```

for

```
</br>XXX
```

Where XXX is any set of characters, by that I mean i have set of words up to 5 words like: `this is set of characters`

ex.

I have:

```
<td>one</td></tr>    
<td>two words</td></tr>    
<td>three words set</td></tr>
```

and i want to replace it to:

```
</br>one    
</br>two words    
</br>three words set
```

Right now I can find the set by:
`<td>(.*?)</td></tr>`

But i dont know how to replace it in the way i want.

Could you help me guys? I'm using builtin "replace tool" in notepad++

Comment: Can the `XXX` contain HTML tags?

Comment: No, XXX is just plain text with spaces

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex in itself is correct, you are capturing your value between the tags (XXX) as Group 1. So in Notepad++:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>

Enable *Regular Expression*

Key point in the *Replace with*: you can access the contents of Group 1 match as **\1** (= XXX).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your search string `<td>(.*?)</td></tr>` seems to be correct.

You can replace by `<br />\1`. (Note that the self-closing `<br>` is not written as `</br>`.)

Comment: The only reason I can think of is: Because *"how can I replace with something from my regex in Notepad++"* can be found out from the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe these instructions can help:

a) Open the text file in Notepad++.
b) In the top menu bar, click Search and select Replace.
c) In the Replace window, on the Replace tab, enter the text you want to find ( i.e. (.*?) ) and the text you want to use as a replacement ( i.e. (.*?) ).

You can also press the keyboard shortcut key Ctrl+H to open the Replace window.

Hope this helps.

Comment: How is this answering the question?